# Why "array.length" returns array object when we put it inside array[]?

Tags: arrays, ruby, random, maxlength

```
rand(array.length)        # returns random index <br>
array[rand(array.length)] # returns random array object
```

I can't understand the logic behind. I would assume that second example also returns random index and then store it in array.

```
kitty = [100,102,104,105]

rand(kitty.length)        # returns index, for example 3 ( or 0,1,2 )
array[rand(kitty.length)] # returns random array object, for example 104 ( or 100,102,105)
```

Comment: Are you asking why `array[some_number]` returns the item in the array at that index?

Comment: What happens when you do `array[3]` (or 0, 1, 2)?  It's the same as your second example.  `rand(kitty.length)` returns an integer that is then used to index `array`.

Comment: Ok, I got it Tony. rand(kitty.length) = index  and array[index] returns array object. So obvious and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `array.sample` would be the best way to get a random element from an array, I believe OP is asking how the chaining of methods works.

When you call: `rand(array.length)` a number is returned, true. However in the case of:

```
array[ rand(array.length) ]
```

a number is returned but then fed immediately into the array call, which gives you the object at that array index.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a tutorial? If so, don trust it. `array.sample` is how to do it.

Comment: Probably a good suggestion, but I'm not sure it really answers the question. It seems more appropriate as a comment or footnote.

Answer (score 0):

**ruby code**

```
kitty = [100,102,104,105]
kitty.sample                #to get random array elements
```

Comment: I don't if this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing is expected:

`array[index]` is a reference to an object in the provided array where *index* is a numeric value that is less than `array.length` since `rand(array.length)` returns a random numeric value less than `array.length` you are effectively accessing an element at a random index of the given array.

The same behavior can be obtained with `array.sample` though and is recommended.

For more information on Ruby's arrays please see the documentation at: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html